# Angular FormControl updateOn blur async validator gets old value

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous, form-control

I have created a custom validator for angular forms which goal is to check whether the text entered in an input is not already used

```
export class CustomValidators {
    static titleNotExists(myService: MyService, category: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            return myService
                .checkTitleAvailability(category, control.value)
                .pipe(
                    map((isAvailable: boolean) =>
                        isAvailable || control.pristine ? null : { titleExists: `An object with this title already exists for category ${category}.` }
                    )
                );
        };
    }
}
```

I want this validator to run only onBlur so that I don't make a request for every single character entered, so for this I set updateOn to 'blur'

```
export class MyModalComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input category: string;
    myForm: FormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', { validators: [Validators.pattern(/^(\w|[&-. ])*$/), Validators.maxLength(100), Validators.required], updateOn: 'blur' }]
        });

    get titleFormControl(): FormControl {
        return <FormControl>this.myForm.get('title');
    }

    constructor(private _myService: MyService, private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.titleFormControl.setAsyncValidators([CustomValidators.titleNotExists(this._myService, category)]);
    }
}
```

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save.focus()" [formGroup]="myForm">
        <input
                [formControl]="titleFormControl"
                [isRequired]="true"
                [label]="'Title'"
        >
            <button
                    #save
                    (click)="save()"
                    [disabled]="!myForm.valid"
                    aria-label="submit"
                    color="primary"
                    mat-raised-button
            >
                SAVE
            </button>
</form>
```

But when I enter values in the input, I can see in my request that the value sent to be checked is never updated (always empty if the input was empty, or the initial value if there was one) and I do not comprehend why this happens...
If I leave updateOn to the default onChange it does work correctly, making a request every character and returning correctly whether it's available or not...

Comment: can you do a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: I will try but doing those usually take me more time than finding an answer

Comment: Isn’t it supposed to be addAsyncValidators..?

Comment: Well I made a stackblitz that works so idk what's going on
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kjgzqg?file=src%2Fmy-modal%2Fmy-modal.component.ts

Comment: Might be coming from a custom component made by a colleague in our library so probably a headache to find the issue.